# Boost factor in MultiFieldQueryParser

Tags: lucene

Can I boost different fields in MultiFieldQueryParser with different factors?
Also, what is the maximum boost factor value I can assign to a field?

Thanks a ton!
Ed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`MultiFieldQueryParser` has a [constructor][1] that accepts a map of boosts. You use it with something like this:

```
String[] fields = new String[] { "title", "keywords", "text" };
HashMap<String,Float> boosts = new HashMap<String,Float>();
boosts.put("title", 10);
boosts.put("keywords", 5);
MultiFieldQueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(
    fields, 
    new StandardAnalyzer(),
    boosts
);
```

As for the maximum boost, I'm not sure, but you shouldn't think about boost in absolute terms anyway. Just use a ratio of boosts that makes sense. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342937/maximum-boost-factor).

[1]: https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/MultiFieldQueryParser.html#MultiFieldQueryParser(org.apache.lucene.util.Version, java.lang.String[], org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer, java.util.Map)

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer....am using lucene.net version 2.0.0.4
I dont see MultiFieldQueryParser constructor accepting boost values.

MultiFieldQueryParser multiFieldQueryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fields, _analyzer);

May I know which Lucene version are u using?

Thanks.

Comment: The boosts parameter was available only in Lucene 2.4. If you can't upgrade you might consider copying the code into your own MyMutliFieldQueryParser. It's not that much code.

Comment: You may have to port the code from java... I couldn't find lucene.net's source code online (svn.apache.org is down ATM).