# How to use MultiFieldQueryParser along with boost factor?

Tags: lucene

I have indexed documents in Lucene based on three fields: **title**, **address**, **city**. Now I want to build my query say, **C A B** so that I can retrieve the documents as follows:

**C** must be present in the **title** field of the documents and either **A** or **B** must be present in either of **address** and **city** fields of the matched documents. The documents that have A present in either of those fields should get higher score or higher boost. Here **A**, **B**, **C** may be single terms or phrases.

I am new to Lucene. I do not have any experience of framing such complex queries. In this context I have read the post [Boost factor in MultiFieldQueryParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551724/boost-factor-in-multifieldqueryparser)
But this post does not answer my question. So if anyone please help me to solve this I will be really grateful.

Comment: Is what you have in mind something like: `+title: C +(address: A B city: A B)^2` where `2` is the boost level?

Answer (score 0):

> title:C AND (address:A^2 OR city:A^2 OR address:B OR city:B)

Answer (score 0):

Don't get caught up on reading about MultiFieldQueryParser, that isn't really what you need for this.  Standard QueryParser syntax will serve your purposes you fine.

See the Lucene QueryParser [syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html)

A query like:

```
+title:C +((address:A city:A)^2 address:B city:B)
```

Should do nicely.

To explain a bit:

`+title:C` - require a match on title:C.  No results will be returned that don't match this condition.

`+(....)` - require a match on the subquery contained inside.  As long as a match is found on any one of the optional queries contained within the parentheses is matched, this will be satisfied.

`(address:A city:A)^2` - You prefer a match on A, these two queries are boosted more heavily with `^2`.

Comment: Here if I use MultiFieldQueryParser will the result be wrong? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Yes, MultiFieldQueryParser is designed to execute the entire query against a list of fields.  As such, it isn't correct for your case.  The StandardQueryParser, as described, will serve your purpose just fine.